# Этот сложный юмор Жванецкого

Tags: стилистика, тропы, фигуры-речи, парадоксы

Не могу определить, какие стилистические приемы/тропы/фигуры использованы в выделенных жирным шрифтом местах.

Жванецкий рассказывает про Одессу:

> 1. Дачи здесь маленькие – **квартиры без крыш**. **Засыпаешь один, просыпаешься впятером**.

Что имеется в виду?

> 2. **Август** у нас **лучший** месяц в году, но **сентябрь лучше августа**.

То есть сначала делается заявление, что август лучший - но тут же оно опровергается. Получается абсурд какой-то. Не могу найти, что это за троп/фигура.

> 3. Художники из Одессы уезжают. **Ее надо заканчивать**, как школу. **Все жизненные пути одесситов упираются в море**.

Полный текст рассказа "Одесса" [здесь](http://odesskiy.com/zhvanetskiy-tom-1/odessa.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Дачи здесь маленькие – квартиры без крыш. Засыпаешь один, просыпаешься впятером.

Это такая самоирония одесситов: все дачи сдаются туристам, даже маленькие клетушки, а в них набивается народу - сколько можно поставить кроватей. Имеется в виду, что снял квартиру-дачу, уснул, а проснулся - хозяйка за ночь ещё подселила квартирантов. Бывают такие квартиры и в прямом смысле без крыш - веранды с навесом, всё равно жарко, крыши не нужны. Худ. особенность - антонимы засыпаешь-просыпаешься, контекстные антонимы один-впятером. А "квартиры без крыш" можно назвать и метафорической  иронией: маленькие, но вмещают много (как "резиновые квартиры"),  "без крыши"-можно понять ещё и как "без уюта" (дом, уют - крыша над головой). Но сам Жванецкий никогда не заморачивался насчёт названия тропа, у него бывает  в одном несколько. Просто добрый юмор с глубоким дном-подтекстом.

2. Август у нас лучший месяц в году, но сентябрь лучше августа. - Сами сказали: абсурд, т. е. худ. особенность парадокс.
3. Художники из Одессы уезжают. Ее **надо заканчивать**, как школу. -метафора, прояснённая сравнением "как школу" - в школе не учатся вечно, из неё выпускаются, когда уже там нечему учиться, всё постиг. Вот и художники должны уезжать, чтобы постичь многообразие жизни, а в Одессе всё просто и предсказуемо, изучил - езжай дальше, как сделал он сам.
4. Все жизненные пути одесситов упираются в море.- метафора: кем бы ни был  одессит, он будет связан с морем - моряк, рыбак, портовый рабочий, поэт, художник, кораблестроитель, продавец, жена моряка, даже актёры связаны с морем.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а об этом примере можно сказать, что выделенные слова являются **парономазами** (и с их помощью возникает каламбур): Старички сидят на скамейках у ворот с выражением лица: «Стой! Кто идет?!». Когда вы возвращаетесь к себе с дамой, вы **покрываетесь** потом и не знаете, чем ее **прикрыть**.

Comment: Да, видимо, можно, хотя корни одинаковые, это не паронимы, а однокоренные слова,но здесь явно обыгрывается одинаковое звучание при  разном смысле.

Comment: А почему нельзя сказать каламбур как фигура речи?

Answer (score 0):

Очень трудно объяснять, почему анекдот смешной. Так и со Жванецким. Еще сложнее такой текст разложить на прокрустовом ложе тропов. Пока не поймешь смысл, охарактеризовать невозможно. А смысл бывает не так прост.

> Все жизненные пути одесситов упираются в море

Здесь про то, что из Одессы уезжают "за море". Смесь фигур, как и все у Жванецкого. Но вообще-то это грустная ирония, выраженная через замену слова в выражении "упираются в стену". Не знаю как назвать такую фигуру... Антитеза, может.

> Ее надо заканчивать, как школу

Ироническое сравнение (Одесса и школа), метонимия (покидать и заканчивать). Плюс игра слов со значением "заканчивать".

> Август у нас лучший месяц в году, но сентябрь лучше августа.

Это да, парадокс, но он для Одессы как бы и не парадокс вовсе. Так там не только говорят, там так *думают*.

Вот что два одессита о том написали.

> Происшедшее нарастание улыбок и чувств напоминало рукопись композитора
>   Франца Листа, где на первой странице указано играть «быстро», на
>   второй — «очень быстро», на третьей — «гораздо быстрее», на четвертой
>   — «быстро как только возможно» и все-таки на пятой — «еще быстрее».

(Ильф и Петров, ЗТ)

Насчет "домов без крыш" у меня тоже большое сомнение в трактовке Людмилы, но тут я даже не могу предложить своего.

Answer (score 0):

Дачи здесь маленькие – квартиры без крыш. Засыпаешь один, просыпаешься впятером. Я думаю, во-первых, обыгрывается многозначность слова "крыша", т. е. "крыша" как кровля и как прикрытие, покровительство, защита. Кроме того, используются контекстные антонимы "один - впятером". Ведь понятно, что невозможно заснуть одному и проснуться впятером, но если квартира без крыши, то и доступ туда вроде бы свободен...

Август у нас лучший месяц в году, но сентябрь лучше августа. Слово "лучший" - это превосходная степень прилагательного от "хороший". Превосходная степень обозначает признак предмета в наивысшей степени, лучше которого быть не может. Однако оказывается, что всё же "сентябрь лучше августа". По - моему, это и гипербола, и отчасти контекстная антитеза.

Ее (Одессу) надо заканчивать, как школу. Во - первых, понятно, что заканчивают не саму Одессу, а прощаются с каким - то отрезком жизненного пути, жизненными уроками, проблемами. И в этом смысле это явная метонимия. А во - вторых, сравнительных союз "как", который следует далее, говорит о том, что это и сравнение. 
И последнее, я не знаю, кто и почему выделял жирным шрифтом именно ЭТИ места. Но по- моему, глупо пытаться объяснять природу юмора, ссылаясь только на  стилистические приемы/тропы/фигуры. Юмористический текст люблю воспринимать в единстве формы и содержания.